# Node JS UDP server: Offset into buffer too large (Error)

Tags: node.js, server, udp

I am trying to send a message to a client by doing:

```
server.send(new Buffer("Hello World!"), data.port, data.ip);
```

but I always get the following error:

```
dgram.js:256
throw new RangeError('Offset into buffer too large');
      ^
RangeError: Offset into buffer too large
at Socket.send (dgram.js:256:11)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/lchost/fishy.io/server/custom_modules/game.js:50:14)
at Socket.emit (events.js:98:17)
at UDP.onMessage (dgram.js:441:8)
```

Any Ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have done this:

```
server.send(new Buffer("Hello World!"), 0, 0, data.port, data.ip);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = new Buffer("Hello World!");

server.send(data, 0, data.length, data.port, data.ip);
```

Tested in node v0.10.29